# Display Default value into dropdown list in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In MVC4 razor application @Html.DropDownListFor providing selectlist using ViewBag 
but how to set default value to that drop down is not getting.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SlpCode, new SelectList(ViewBag.SalesEmployee1, "Value", "Description"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

for that I am tried

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SlpCode, new SelectList(ViewBag.SalesEmployee1, "Value", "Description", (Model.SlpCode==-1)), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but still it will not be work.
what is another solution for that?

Comment: You need to set the value of `SlpCode` in the controller before you pass the model to the view. If it matches one of the option values (the `Value` property of `SalesEmployee1`) then that option will be selected

Comment: I am try this and this works.       Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Simply use `ViewModel.SlpCode = "DefaultValue"` to set DDList default value before returning view in your controller `GET` method, assume you have a viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i am doing for drop down list

controller code

```
        public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        Contact homeViewModel = new Contact();
        homeViewModel.subject = new List<Subject>();
        homeViewModel.subject.Add(new Subject { Id = 1, subject1 = "General Customer Service" });
        homeViewModel.subject.Add(new Subject { Id = 2, subject1 = "Suggestions" });
        homeViewModel.subject.Add(new Subject { Id = 3, subject1 = "Product Support" });

        homeViewModel.Selectedid = 1; //this sets the default value for your dropdown

        return View(homeViewModel);
    }
```

Model code :

```
public class Contact
 {   [Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill the following")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Correct Username")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})$", ErrorMessage = "Please provide valid email id")]
    public string email { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> subject { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill the following")]
    public string message { get; set; }
    public int Selectedid { get; set; }
}
```

View Code :

```
@Html.DropDownList("Selectedid", new SelectList(Model.subject, "Id",    "subject1", Model.Selectedid), new { @class = "form-control", id = "subject", required = "required" })
```